# react automatically remove vendor prefix in inline style?

Tags: reactjs

I am using css vendor prefix in inline-style in my component,

because some of my target browsers need it.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            r: 0
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div style={{
                'WebkitTransform': 'rotate(' + this.state.r + 'deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(' + this.state.r + 'deg)'
            }} onClick={this._click}>
                some text
            </div>
            );
    },

    _click: function() {
        this.setState({
            r: -100
        });
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

as you can see, I use `WebkitTransform` and `transform`, but what react rendered was just only `transform`, how do I make it to render the `-webkit-transform`?

Comment: I think `WebkitTransform` and `transform` do the same thing, why don't  you  use `WebKitTransform` or `transform` only?

Comment: @chenkehxx I tried it before, even when I only use `WebkitTransform`, it will be render into `transform`, and `WebkitTransform` and `transform` do not do the same thing, that's why I need vendor prefix for compatibility issue.

Comment: This is interesting... not something that I have noticed before.  I put your code into JSBin (http://jsbin.com/bawugivipu/4/edit?html,js,output), loaded up FireFox with only the "WebkitTransform" and there was no style added.  Opened the link in Chrome, and I see "transform" applied - which I didn't put there.  Perhaps React does something smart with prefixes?  I can't seem to find any docs on this (maybe its a JSBin thing?).

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7372#event-738976023